# Dataguard the datafiles are created in another diskgroup

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g, dataguard, standby, oracle-asm

I have a recently made physical dataguard configuration and everything works correctly so far, but I've noticed that the datafiles that are created in the primary are created in the standby in a different route, the environment is as follows:

Primary - db_name: oradb, db_unique_name: oradb. Oracle 11gR2. ASM storage. Diskgoups: SYS, SYS2 and DATA
Standby - db_name: oradb, db_unique_name: oradb2. Oracle 11gR2. ASM storage. Diskgoups: SYS, SYS2 and DATA.

When creating a tablespace in the primary, example:
CREATE TABLESPACE TBS_DATA DATAFILE
  '+DATA' SIZE 50M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 1M MAXSIZE 100M ...
the respective datafile is created in the diskgroup DATA ... +DATA/oradb/datafile/tbs_data...
all good, the doubt that I have is that I realized that in the Standby database the datafile is created in the diskgroup SYS +SYS/oradb2/datafile/tbs_data...
, what should I do to create the datafiles in the correct path, that is +DATA/oradb2/datafile/tbs_data...?
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the 'db_create_file_dest' parameter which was it defined as "SYS". Therefore the datafiles were created in said path.